# How to make thread sleep according to progressValue of seekBar

Tags: android, multithreading, flash, android-camera, android-seekbar

I am making app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.surpax.ledflashlight.panel&hl=en). Everything is working fine but there is a little problem. I want to change duration of Flash (ON/OFF) of Flash Light by value of progress bar. Means thread should sleep by duration **progressValue**.

When onProgressChanged method is called, I want call method flash_toggle_times(final int delay) to change value of sleep(delay) everytime progressValue is changed.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {flash_toggle_times(progressValue);}
```

Here is code for flash_toggle_times(SeekBar seekbar, int progressValue, Boolean fromUser)

```
public void flash_toggle_times(final int delay) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();     
    final Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);


    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Switch on the cam for app's life
                if (mCamera == null) {
                    // Turn on Cam
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                    try {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }



                while(positionON )
                {
                 if(delay > 0){
                    toggleFlashLight();
                    sleep(delay);
                }
                }

                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e){ 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
}

public void turnOn(){
     if (mCamera != null) {
            // Turn on LED
            mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
     }
     lightON = true;
}
public void turnOff(){
    // Turn off flashlight
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        if (mParams.getFlashMode().equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
            mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
        }
    }
    lightON = false;
}
private void toggleFlashLight() {
    if (!lightON) {
        turnOn();
    } else {
        turnOff();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please narrow down your problem and source code so that more people feel invited to help you?

Comment: I have edited question.

Comment: Now I kind of grasp how you intend your code to work, but having limited java skills and much more C# skills, and in C# I learned how to replace concurrency with Thread by BackgroundWorker, and now by Task. So I am not the best person to help you here. My questions: does java not have something better for Thread? An alternative for Thread may be easier to program, and fix your problem. And what is your exact problem, where does this not work, what happens instead? This would invite others to help you too.

Comment: @Roland For First call thread goes to sleep for `int delay` duration, but as delay is final when second time `flash_toggle_times(final int delay)` method is called and again delay value is provided, App crashes. Problem will be solved if I change Parameter from `final int delay` to `int delay`. But for thread delay should be final. And I am stuck here.